# Index out of range - Quicksort in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the quicksort algorithm, but I keep getting list index out of range.

What exactly is out of range at quicksort(array, left, Pi
vot-1)?

```
def partition(array,left,right):
    #If pivot is not on leftmost, swap to make it leftmost
    Pivot = array[0]
    i = left+1
    for j in range(i,right):
        if array[j] < Pivot:
            #Swap array[j] and array[i]
            array[j], array[i] = array[i], array[j]
            i += 1;
    #Swap pivot and A[i-1]        
    array[Pivot], array[i-1] = array[i-1], array[Pivot]
    return Pivot

def quicksort(array,left,right):
    # Base case
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array
    #Choose pivot
    Pivot = partition(array,left,right);
    #Partition array around a pivot
    #Recursive call
    quicksort(array, left, Pivot-1)
    quicksort(array, Pivot + 1, right)

print quicksort([1,5,3,4,9,10],0,5)
```

Error messages:

```
File "quicksort.py", line 25, in <module>
print quicksort([1,5,3,4,9,10],0,5)

File "quicksort.py", line 22, in quicksort
quicksort(array, left, Pivot-1)

File "quicksort.py", line 22, in quicksort
quicksort(array, left, Pivot-1)

File "quicksort.py", line 19, in quicksort
Pivot = partition(array,left,right);

File "quicksort.py", line 11, in partition
array[Pivot], array[i-1] = array[i-1], array[Pivot]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Post the Error message..

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمورError messages added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `partition()`,

```
Pivot = array[0]
```

Here `Pivot` looks like the value of pivot element. However,

```
#Swap pivot and A[i-1]        
array[Pivot], array[i-1] = array[i-1], array[Pivot]
```

Here you use it as index to array. Thus it's very likely to be out of legal array index range.

Answer (score 2):

During third iteration the value of `pivot` and `array` are as below

```
[10, 1, 3, 4, 9, 5] 10
```

In which you try to get `array[Pivot]`

Since it has only six elements ,So only the `index  out of range error is thrown`

Answer (score 2):

May be this may help.

```
def partition(array, begin, end):
    pivot = begin
    for i in xrange(begin+1, end+1):
        if array[i] <= array[begin]:
            pivot += 1
            array[i], array[pivot] = array[pivot], array[i]
    array[pivot], array[begin] = array[begin], array[pivot]
    return pivot


def quicksort(array, begin=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(array) - 1
    if begin >= end:
        return
    pivot = partition(array, begin, end)
    quicksort(array, begin, pivot-1)
    quicksort(array, pivot+1, end)
```

Comment: add return in `quicksort()`